# Check if executable is in the PATH using qmake

Tags: qt, qt5, doxygen, qmake

I have a custom build target in my `*.pro` file:

```
docs.commands = doxygen $$PWD/../docs/Doxyfile

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += docs
POST_TARGETDEPS += docs
```

which runs `Doxygen` as a post build event. The problem is, if someone builds the project and hasn't installed `doxygen` the build fails. Is it possible to check whether or not `doxygen` is installed on the machine that builds the project so that I run the `doxygen` command only if `doxygen` is installed and added to the system `PATH`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With qmake, you can try this:

```
DOXYGEN_BIN = $$system(which doxygen)

isEmpty(DOXYGEN_BIN) {
        message("Doxygen not found")
}
```

Another option could be the following one:

```
DOXYGEN_BIN = $$system( echo $$(PATH) | grep doxygen )

isEmpty(DOXYGEN_BIN) {
        message("Doxygen not found")
}
```

**BTW, if you are using CMake**

You can achieve that using

```
find_package(Doxygen)
```

Example:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Doxygen)
if (NOT DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Doxygen is needed to build the documentation.")
endif()
```

You have more information in this site:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindDoxygen.html

Comment: Hm, but was the question about `CMake`? It was about **qmake**.

Comment: This is great for `CMake`, but unfortunately I'm currently not using `CMake`, just `QMake`. Is there something similar for `QMake`? Or I didn't understand well?

Comment: Oh... sorry :( My fault!

Comment: @Tarod Np, keep it, IMO this is also useful.

Comment: @Tarod Works like charm, thanks! BTW, if using Windows, one can use `where` instead of `which` to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @Jacob Krieg Well, the important thing is to find a solution :) Good luck and enjoy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Try this on your .pro file:

```
# Check if Doxygen is installed on the default Windows location
win32 {
    exists( "C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin\doxygen.exe" ) {
        message( "Doxygen exists")
        # execute your logic here
    }
}
# same idea for Mac
macx {
    exists( "/Applications/doxygen.app/ ... " ) {
        message( "Doxygen exists")
    }
}
```

**Update**

Using @Tarod answer you can make it cross compatible with the following

```
# Check if Doxygen is installed on Windows (tested on Win7)
win32 {
    DOXYGEN_BIN = $$system(where doxygen)

    isEmpty(DOXYGEN_BIN) {
        message("Doxygen not found")
        # execute your logic here
    } else {
        message("Doxygen exists in " $$DOXYGEN_BIN)
    }
}

# Check if Doxygen is installed on Linux or Mac (tested on Ubuntu, not yet on the Mac)
unix|max {
    DOXYGEN_BIN = $$system(which doxygen)

    isEmpty(DOXYGEN_BIN) {
        message("Doxygen not found")
        # execute your logic here
    } else {
        message("Doxygen exists in " $$DOXYGEN_BIN)
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the user installs `doxygen` in another directory than the default one? Isn't it possible to check the PATH variable to determine that?

Answer (score 1):

Qt docs say:

> To obtain the contents of an environment value when qmake is run, use the $$(...) operator...

i.e.:

```
PATH_VAR = $$(PATH)
DOXYGEN = "doxygen"
contains(PATH_VAR, DOXYGEN) {
    message("Doxygen found")
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `PATH_VAR` has to be a list separated by spaces in order for this to work. I just tested and it doesn't work.

Comment: @JacobKrieg, what if you split it with `$$split($$(PATH), " ")`?

Comment: @JacobKrieg I've just updated my answer. It's a little bit tricky :)